# How to obtain indirect effect in SPSS PROCESS Model 8?

Tags: spss, mediation

as part of my research I am using SPSS Process Model 8.

I get the result that the a-path is not moderated and the index of moderated mediation is also not significant. However, the conditional indirect effects show that the indirect effect is significant at one condition (X=1) of the IV (dichotomy variable), whereas it is not significant at the other condition (X=0).

Can I now assume that there is no meditated moderation, since the influence of the moderators is not significantly different at X=1 and X=0? Then how is it possible that the indirect effect becomes significant under one condition and not the other, if the index is not significant?

**Based on PROCESS MODEL 8, how can I conclude whether I have an indirect effect at all (independent of the moderator)?**

Comment: Please define "SPSS Process Model 8".

Comment: With Model 8 I refer the moderated mediation model in which the a path as well as the direct path are moderated

Comment: That helps narrow it down a little. There are many path models that could be mediators. Could you draw the path diagram?

Comment: I guess [this is SPSS process model 8](http://www.regorz-statistik.de/en/process_model_8_moderated_mediation.html).